# Extension method return using generics

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

Is it possible to return a [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6(v=vs.80).aspx) type using [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977(v=VS.90).aspx)?

For example, I have the following method:

```
// Convenience method to obtain a field within a row (as a double type) 
public static double GetDouble(this DataRow row, string field) {
    if (row != null && row.Table.Columns.Contains(field))
    {
        object value = row[field];
        if (value != null && value != DBNull.Value)
            return Convert.ToDouble(value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is currently used as follows:

```
double value = row.GetDouble("tangible-equity");
```

but I would like to use the following code:

```
double value = row.Get<double>("tangible-equity");
```

Is this possible and if so, what would the method look like?

Comment: BTW, just so you know, you can simply write "double value = row.Get("tangible-equity");" and skip the "<double>" because the compiler will figure it out

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about this one:

```
    public static T Get<T>(this DataRow row, string field) where T: IConvertible 
    {
        if (row != null && row.Table.Columns.Contains(field))
        {
            object value = row[field];
            if (value != null && value != DBNull.Value)
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
        }
        return default(T);
    }
```

[**Convert.ChangeType**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx) is much more flexible handling conversions as opposed to just casting. This pretty much reflects your original code, just generic.

Comment: should support all types that implement IConvertible

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. It could be something like the following:

```
// Convenience method to obtain a field within a row (as a T type) 
public static T Get<T>(this DataRow row, string field) {
    if (row != null && row.Table.Columns.Contains(field))
    {
        object value = row[field];
        if (value != null && value != DBNull.Value)
            return (T)value;
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: That will happen if your database column is not of the same type as T.  @BrokenGlass's answer should properly convert objects of different types.

Comment: That'll happen often enough handling data types from the DB

Comment: Agreed. Better to use Convert.ChangeType()

Answer (score 1):

The DataRow has an extension method called [Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that will do very much what you are trying to do.  I'm not exactly sure how it will behave with a null value on a double (I know it will handle nullable types).  This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but is worth a look.

```
double value = row.Field<double>("tangible-equity");
```

Comment: It's not Linq.  It's just an extension method on DataRow.  It is almost exactly what you are trying to build.

Comment: I think you have to add ref to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll